# Rails 4, collection_select, HABTM create objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Disclaimer: New to Rails and Web development in general.

I have a HABTM relationship between Events and Tags. When I create or update an Event, I can assign/remove relationships to preexisting tags via `collection_Select`:

```
<%= f.label :name, "Tag" %>
<%= f.collection_select( :tag_ids, Tag.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true}) %>
```

I'd also like to add new tags with this same field. I've found 3 gems/plugins that support this functionality which all rely on javascript:

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#tags

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

[loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

The select2 link is pretty much exactly what I'd like to implement. I've yet to find a native rails implementation of this functionality. Can this be done with just rails/ruby, if so how?